# Add a file type

Tags: uploads

I am trying to upload java files to my WordPress blog but it does not let me upload any files with `.java` extension.

I get this error:

> ".java” has failed to upload due to an error
>
> File type does not meet security guidelines. Try another.

How do I add `.java` extension so that it allows me to upload java source code?

I am using WordPress version 3.0.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use filter '[upload_mimes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes)'.

```
<?php    
add_filter('upload_mimes','add_java_files');

function add_java_files($mimes)
{
    // Add file extension 'extension' with mime type 'mime/type'
    $mimes['java'] = 'text/x-java-source';
    return $mimes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this nice function that does the trick

```
<?php
function addUploadMimes($mimes) {
    $mimes = array_merge($mimes, array(
        'tmbundle|tmCommand|tmDragCommand|tmSnippet|tmLanguage|tmPreferences' => 'application/octet-stream'
    ));
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'addUploadMimes');
?>
```

you can add more file types by adding them on `"'tmbundle|tmCommand|tmDragCommand|tmSnippet|tmLanguage|tmPreferences'"`

separated by a pipe (|)