# How can I upload a file with no extension

Tags: uploads

I am trying to upload a configuration file so I can include a link to it in my post. And I get a Security error, because the file type is not allowed.

My config file has no extension.

I found this question: [Adding file types in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/adding-file-types-in-wordpress)

Is there a way that I can add the mime type of '' for a "No Extension" type?

Comment: couldn't you just upload it via ftp?

Comment: @Chip Well, I can certainly get the file in the uploads directory (I can simply mv or FTP it there). But I can't figure out how to get it to show in "Media" once it's there, so I can link to it from WP.

Comment: I have same issue. I want to upload the file (having no format) from front-end but I got the error "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.I have tried all solution available on internet, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add `.txt` to the file? It's probably the safest thing to do. If you need the file name to display without the extension, you can always filter the string.

Comment: Yeah, this had occurred to me as well, and I suppose is a valid solution. It just adds another step for anyone who would want to download my config "as-is", because they would have to rename it to remove the ".txt"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to install plugins atm to test, but maybe this plugin would work for the files you FTP - [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server)